# How can I select XElements where Attribute ... (LINQ2XML)

Tags: xml, linq

How can I select the Value where id == id && key == key with Linq

xml:

```
<Localization>    
  <Module id="Customers">
    <CultureCode>de-DE</CultureCode>
    <Key>General</Key>
    <Value>Allgemeine Kunden</Value>
  </Module>     
  <Module id="Contract">
    <CultureCode>de-DE</CultureCode>
    <Key>General</Key>
    <Value>Allgemeine Verträge</Value>
  </Module>     
</localization>
```

this my approach

methode(string module, string key)...

```
var value = (from l in localization.Elements("Localization").Elements("Module")
             where l.Attribute("id").Equals(module) && l.Element("Key").Value.Equals(key)
             select l.Element("Value").Value);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `module` is a string, the problem is you're comparing an `XAttribute` with a `string`.

Here's a fixed version of the query:

```
var value = (from l in localization.Elements("Localization").Elements("Module")
             where (string) l.Attribute("id") == module && 
                   l.Element("Key").Value == key
             select l.Element("Value").Value);
```

Note that I'm casting the `XAttribute` to string rather than using the `Value` property so that if the `id` attribute doesn't exist, it will just not match rather than blowing up.

If you want a single value, you should call `Single`, `First`, `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` on the result depending on what semantics you want.

Comment: thx! that works fine for me, I had problems with "localization.Elements("Localization").Elements("Module")" too, and i change this to: localization.Elements() and now work it : )